# "No data exists for the row column" error returned by 'OleDbDataReader'

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader

I am trying to use [OleDbDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it is returning this error:

```
No data exists for the row column
```

I am using an Access database. Can anyone help me identify the source of this error? Here is my code:

```
private void UpdateStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(
        "select * from Students where SID= " + U_ID, con);

    con.Open();
    OleDbDataReader rd = da.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (rd.Read())
    {
        //txtId.Text = U_ID;
        txtId.Text = rd["SID"].ToString();
    }

    rd.Close();
}
```

Comment: Consider implementing `using()` statements and try/catch.  Also, you may want to change your code to `if(rd.HasRows) { while(rd.Read()) {  do stuff } }`. Those suggestions dont address your actual question though

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
var queryString = "select * from Students where SID= " + U_ID, con;
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        txtId.Text = reader["SID"].ToString();
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: now it does not give me the error no "data exists for the row column"

Comment: because your query result's is empty, if you try this query in your database, your query return null, i'am sure user1587902

Comment: but it skips the while loop and goes immediatly to reader.close();

Comment: @user1587902 Its mean reader.Read() is not getting any data to read after execution of query. You should check your "U_ID" if this really exist in database.